# How to get Instagram user ID (from local or remote application)?

Tags: android, instagram

I need to get user's Instagram ID which I will use to query another API. Now, what is the correct approach to this:

1. Check if a user has Instagram app installed on his phone. If not, send him to Google Play? Then when he installs the app and creates an account, you pull his ID from the local installation - is this possible at all?
2. Send a user to the web browser to login then do what? Can we get a reponse from a browser and is this pain worth of trouble?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it two ways.

**Way 1** is described on [Instagram Developer](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#) under "Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication". You can fetch it from Android app using `WebView` and monitoring `onPageStarted`.

**Way 2** is to use 3rd party library. I used [android-instagram-oauth](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth). So when you initialize and start Intagram pop-up via

```
InstagramApp mApp = new InstagramApp(this, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, CALLBACK_URL);
mApp.setListener(...);
mApp.authorize();
```

The class `InstagramApp` will create object `InstagramSession` (also part of this library) and it will save details to shared preferences.

And that's it. I hope someone will use this so you don't spend 3 days figuring this out like I did.

Comment: I think your methods are pretty dedicated but I feel like they're a bit too difficult to follow and execute

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, just go to https://www.instagram.com/[instagram@]/?__a=1.
And then search for `id`. It will show `"id":"xxxxxxxxxx"`

Hope this helps.